# Connecting to Siemens NX server from python (NXOpen); pythonnet GetObject TypeError

Tags: python, typeerror, remoting, python.net, nxopen

I am trying to grab the Session object from a Siemens NX server (on the same machine, i.e. localhost). 
I am using python 3.6 with pythonnet, since the remote connection (apparently) only works through .NET - I am VERY new to pythonnet (only tried it for this one function so far).

I need the Session object via remote because I want to grab some user inputs from the interface, therefore batch via run_journal is not an option.

The approach is based on what i found here: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/276, but i get the error "**TypeError: No method matches given arguments for GetObject**"

```
import NXOpen
import clr
import System

theSession = System.Activator.GetObject(NXOpen.Session, "http://localhost:4574/Session")
```

I have also tried with `GetObject(type(NXOpen.Session), ...)` with the same error.

How do I have to feed the NXOpen object type into the GetObject function?

alternatively, are there any better ways to remotely connect to a Siemens NX Session using Python?

The server is the sample NXOpen .NET remote server as found in \Siemens\NX 12.0\UGOPEN\SampleNXOpenApplications.NET\RemotingExample\Server

Comment: In C# there is a `typeof(Session)` which will do the job. Not sure if this works with python too. Also make sure NX loaded your host dll!

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: @essigwurst: NX is serving well, and I can't code C# well enough to try anything there.

Comment: @Liuk: Haven't found a solution yet, sorry...

Answer (score 3):

Late, but it seems i found a solution after all. First, as i installed python 'for all users', i copied all NXOpen libraries in the NX python module directory (i doesn't use an IDE, just Notepad++).

Here's a working example, runs fine with `python.exe file.py` and a .NET remoting server.

```
import clr
from System import Activator

import sys
import math

# Managed NXOpen DLL's goes also in this directory
sys.path.append('C:/Siemens/NX 11/NXBIN/python')

clr.AddReference('NXOpen')
import NXOpen

def main() : 

    m_Session = Activator.GetObject(NXOpen.Session, "http://127.0.0.1:4567/NXOpenSession")
    m_WorkPart = m_Session.Parts.Work

    print(m_Session.Parts.Display.FullPath)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```