# How to use the SIEMENS NX's "NXOpen" API in Python?

Tags: python, cad, siemens-nx

The Python code I wanted to run is:

```
import nxopen as nx
import os

def get_mass_properties(file_path):

    if not os.path.exists(file_path):
        raise ValueError(f"File not found: {file_path}")
    if not os.access(file_path, os.R_OK):
        raise PermissionError(f"Insufficient permissions to access file: {file_path}")

    with nx.Session() as session:
        workpart = session.parts.open(file_path)

        bodies = workpart.bodies
        if len(bodies) != 1:
            raise RuntimeError("Unsupported file format: multiple solids found")
        solid_body = bodies[0]
        
        mass = solid_body.GetMass()

        massprop = [mass]

        workpart.close()
        session.close()

    return massprop

massproperties = get_mass_properties("D:/NX Files/model1.prt")
```

How do I use the NXOpen Python Library which accesses the NX CAD API? I tried installing the 'NXOpen' Library with pip and when I ran my code, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Coding\NXOpen\basic 2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import nxopen as nx
  File "C:\Users\johan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\nxopen\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import cad
  File "C:\Users\johan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\nxopen\cad\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .code import *
  File "C:\Users\johan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\nxopen\cad\code.py", line 3, in <module>
    import NXOpen
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'NXOpen'
```

PLease help me with this!

Comment: Update `py -m pip install nxopen --upgrade`.   Released: Jan 4, 2024

Comment: @toyotaSupra I did what you asked me to do and got this 'already up to date' kinda notice:
PS D:\Coding\NXOpen> py -m pip install nxopen --upgrade
Requirement already satisfied: nxopen in c:\users\johan\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (0.0.1)

Comment: Can you run script?

Comment: @toyotaSupra I figured it out on how to run the python code inside nx. but i now do not know how to compile it as a standalone .exe file

Comment: Hi. Here's a small example I wrote some time ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64150032/6348874 You have to look inside the "managed" folder in your NX install directory, there's the source code for the remoting "server" dll, which you have to load on NX startup.